# Trouble updating Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.10

Tags: updates

Newbee here. I'm trying to update ubuntu because every program I try to get from the software center fails. I'm assuming because they don't support 11.10 anymore. If thats not the reason I'd love some help otherwise. But...I tried updating to 12.10 and that failed so my next intention is to install 12.10 from the raw cd, which I have downloaded. It's too big to put on a cd so I'd like to do upload it to my Ipod and run it from that. Is this possible and how do I.

Comment: 11.10 will be supported until April 2013. Until then you should be able to upgrade to 12.04 LTS with no issue. If that is not possible please do post the errors you get so we can help you. **Do not use your iPod as an installation medium.**

Answer (score 0):

An iPod is not very ideal for doing an install I suppose.

A better way is grabbing a 2Gb USB memory stick and install Ubuntu on it with the startup disc creator (you'll find it in your Ubuntu-installation, it's a standard program). 
After you've done that simply boot (set your bootoptions right) from the memory stick and do the installation.

May I remind you that 12.04 has a full 5 years support ?

Another way of installing on a stick can be done with Unetbootin, but of course you knew that one ..... ;)

More info on [THIS website of Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/)

Succes !